# Moles with InternalsVisibleTo creates "Assembly reference invalid" warning

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moles, pex-and-moles

Another year, another question about Moles. I've got an assembly with an internal sealed class  that I'd like to mole in the test project that I use for unit tests.

According to the Moles documentation I should add an

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "MyAssembly.Moles" )]
```

attribute so I can access the internal class from my test project. However, this unfortunately doesn't work as "MyAssembly" is strongly signed.

Therefore, following the documentation, I added the Public Key to the line above, resulting in

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "MyAssembly.Moles, PublicKey=0123456..." )]
```

Unfortunately this now gives me the following error when compiling "MyAssembly":

> Assembly reference 'MyMoles.Moles, PublicKey=0123456...' is invalid and cannot be resolved

The documentation says that "...the Moles framework always uses the same key to sign the assembly...", but as the compiler says, this does not work. I also checked the generated file "MyAssembly.Moles.dll" with Reflector to verify that I use the correct public key (which I do), so I am stuck as I don't really know what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you are entering the **PUBLIC KEY**, and not the **PUBLIC KEY TOKEN**.

If that doesn't work, use the **secutil**, to get the public key.  The verbose output will include the correct key value.  This is the syntax you need to use:

```
C:\> secutil -hex -s MyAssemblyName.dll
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, somehow the notification must have slipped through. When I run secutil I always get the error message "ERROR: Unable to load assembly "MyAssemblyName.dll"". I made sure that the name is correct by using the command prompt's command completion feature, and I also tried the assembly name with and without the ".dll" extension, unfortunately to no avail.

I then tried to extract the public key from the .snk as described on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.80).aspx, but using that key I get "inaccessible due to its protection level..." error messages.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Entersprise SP1, 64 bit

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce this issue. I'm not sure what the problem or solution is, at this time.

Comment: Thank you. Should I find a solution I will also post an update here.